# Connection from Access to R via DBI

Tags: r, ms-access

I am looking to analyse data in R (using dplyr) contained in an Access database on my laptop. (My first time trying to set up a database connection in R.)

Looking at the tidyverse site, for dplyr to work on the Access data, it seems that the connection must be via the DBI package (rather than RODBC).

I'm struggling with the syntax of dbConnect.

My code for RODBC was

```
base1<-odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=[filepath]/AdventureWorks DW 2012.accdb")
```

My (failed) attempt for DBI is

```
DB <- dbConnect(drv=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)), host=[filepath]/AdventureWorks DW 2012.accdb)
```

What am I doing wrong?

(I'm working on Windows 10 - everything 64 bit.)

Answer (score 9):

I recently needed to convert my RODBC defined db connections to equivalent DBI connections. Here's the original RODBC function:

```
connect_to_access_rodbc <- function(db_file_path) {
   require(RODBC)
   # make sure that the file exists before attempting to connect
   if (!file.exists(db_file_path)) {
     stop("DB file does not exist at ", db_file_path)
   } 

   # Assemble connection strings
   dbq_string <- paste0("DBQ=", db_file_path)
   driver_string <- "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
   db_connect_string <- paste0(driver_string, dbq_string)

   myconn <- odbcDriverConnect(db_connect_string)

   return(myconn)
}
```

As explained [here](http://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/dbplyr.html), the dbplyr package is built from the DBI package. The first argument of the `DBI::dbConnect()` must be an appropriate back-end driver. See the link for a list of drivers. For Access, the `odbc::odbc()` driver is suitable. The second argument the dbConnect function is the full connection string as used in the previous odbcDriverConnect call. With that in mind the following function should connect to your access database:

```
connect_to_access_dbi <- function(db_file_path)  {
  require(DBI)
  # make sure that the file exists before attempting to connect
   if (!file.exists(db_file_path)) {
     stop("DB file does not exist at ", db_file_path)
   }
  # Assemble connection strings
  dbq_string <- paste0("DBQ=", db_file_path)
  driver_string <- "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
  db_connect_string <- paste0(driver_string, dbq_string)

  myconn <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      .connection_string = db_connect_string)
  return(myconn)
}
```

The odbc package documentation presents a more nuanced example as well:
https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc#odbc

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://www.roelpeters.be/solved-importing-microsoft-access-files-accdb-mdb-in-r/), you can still use `odbcConnectAccess2007()` but need 32-bit MS Access 2007 drivers from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255). This worked great for me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33638100)

Answer (score -2):

I just used this a couple days ago.

```
library(RODBC)

# for 32 bit windows
# Connect to Access db
# channel <- odbcConnectAccess("C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/Coding/Microsoft Access/Northwind.mdb")

# Get data
# data <- sqlQuery( channel , paste ("select * from Name_of_table_in_my_database"))


# for 64 bit windows
channel <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/Coding/Microsoft Access/Northwind.mdb")

data <- sqlQuery( channel , paste ("select * from CUSTOMERS"))

odbcCloseAll()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in order to be able to use dplyrI (apparently), I need to make the connection via DBI.

Comment: dplyr. If I'm wrong - can someone help with that? - then I'm good to go. But http://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/dbplyr.html is pretty specific

Comment: Looking further at the DBI package notes, I see I need to define the driver in function dbDriver - I tried this using the Access driver name above (both with and without quotes) and got error message 'couldn't find driver'